# I want the Grub menu to not show up, but some chages don't seem to affect anything

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, windows-8, uefi

I currently have this file setup in the `/etc/default/grub` loader:

```
GRUB_DEFAULT=5
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true
GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
```

I want the Grub menu to not show up at all when I launch the computer and only show up by me spamming shift keys etc... 
5 is set to "Windows 8 (loader)... etc (some file name)

But because the Grub menu keeps coming up it is highlighting Ubuntu 1st and as a result it is automatically booting Ubuntu (which is fine except this is a work computer and I don't really want them to know that I dual booted their system to do some programming :) )

So to reiterate what do I need to change in this file to make the Grub menu not show up at all. I have made other changes to this file aswell for example I tried some #'s and the "windows 8 (loader) etc... but still it shows Grub menu in boot. Buy doing this I also want it to default to Windows 8.

Thank you in advance for any help answering this question.

Comment: I just changed to this and still does not work FYI:   GRUB_DEFAULT=5
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true
GRUB_TIMEOUT=0

Comment: Welcome to AU! Your comment would be a valuable addition to the question. Please [edit] it, if you want to add information. Especially file or program output [listings](/editing-help#code) (with the help of the `{}` button in the editor toolbar) are much more readable there and overall it's best to have everything relevant in one place. Also, comments may be deleted for various reasons.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the GRUB holdshift script.
If you read the GRUB man carefully you woll notice that what you want is not achievable via standard settings.

Just download the script here [GRUB holdshift](https://github.com/hobarrera/grub-holdshift/) and follow the instructions in the readme.